# Flutter: assets audio player

Tags: flutter, audio

I'm a beginner in flutter. And I tried to implement the audio player in the "StatelessWidget" class. But, the widget does not appear on the screen and the following error occurred: "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded." How to solve this problem?

Error:

`The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';

var url = 'https://www.kozco.com/tech/LRMonoPhase4.mp3';
final audioo = AssetsAudioPlayer();

playAudiofromAssets() {
  print("Played");
  audioo.open(
    Audio('assets/audios/ash.mp3'),
  );
  audioo.playOrPause();
}

playAudiofromInt() {
  print("p");
  audioo.open(Audio.network(url));
}

stopAudio() {
  audioo.pause();
}



class CheckboxProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isChecked = false;

  bool get isChecked => _isChecked;

  set isChecked(bool value) {
    _isChecked = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
class CheckboxProviderAudio with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isCheckedAudio = false;

  bool get isCheckedAudio => _isCheckedAudio;

  set isCheckedAudio(bool value) {
    _isCheckedAudio = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}




class CoursePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String logo;
  final String details;
  final String company;


  CoursePage({
    required this. title,
    required this.description,
    required this.image,
    required this.logo,
    required this.details,
    required this.company,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled){
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leadingWidth: 400,
              leading: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Flexible(

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:4),
                      child:  InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Ink.image(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/item-voltar.png"),
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Spacer(),


                 Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                      child:  InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                       //   Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Ink.image(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/component.png"),
                          width: 80,
                          height: 40,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              backgroundColor:  Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
              elevation: 0.0,
              expandedHeight: 300.0,
              floating: false,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                background: Hero(
                  tag: image,
                  child:  Image.asset(
                    image,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];

        },
        body:ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                  child:  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //   Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Ink.image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/item-compartilhar.png"),
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(description,
                   style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),),
              ),
             Text("                             Por: "),
              Image.asset(logo, width: 50, height: 50,),

            ],

          ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10,
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10
                ),
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
            ),

            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text(
                    company,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),


            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text(
                  "Sobre",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text(
               details,
              ),
            ),


      Row(children: [
        Flexible(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[ description  == " Curso"
              ? Row(
                children: [
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (_) => CheckboxProvider(),
                    child: Consumer<CheckboxProvider>(
                      builder: (context, checkboxProvider, _) => Checkbox(
                        value: checkboxProvider.isChecked,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          checkboxProvider.isChecked = value ?? true;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Text(
                    "Fiz esse curso",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),



                ],

              )
                :Row(
                    children: [
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                        create: (_) => CheckboxProviderAudio(),
                        child: Consumer<CheckboxProviderAudio>(
                          builder: (context, checkboxProviderAudio, _) => Checkbox(
                            value: checkboxProviderAudio.isCheckedAudio,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              checkboxProviderAudio.isCheckedAudio = value ?? true;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        "Já ouvi esse tutorial",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                  ],
            )
                ),
         ],
      ),


         Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[ description  == " Curso"
                  ?
                Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 400,
               /* decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),*/
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [


                    Flexible(child:  TextButton(
                    child: Row(

                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.link, color: Colors.white,),
                        Text(
                          "Tenho Interesse",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    style:  const ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.cyan),

                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),

                  ),





                   Flexible(child:
                    TextButton(
                      child: Row(

                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.calendar_month, color: Colors.white,),
                          Text(
                            "Adicionar ao calendário",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      style:  const ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.lightBlueAccent),

                      ),
                      onPressed: () => {},
                    ),
                    )

                   
                  ],
                ),

              )
                : Text("Áudio Player"),
           Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                             Expanded(child:

                             Column(
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                               children: <Widget>[
                                 Text(
                                   "PLAY AUDIO FROM ASSET",
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                       fontSize: 20,
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                 ),
                                 Row(
                                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                   children: <Widget>[


                                     TextButton.icon(
                                       onPressed: playAudiofromAssets,
                                       style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                         foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                       ),
                                       icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                                       label: Text(""),

                                     ),

                                     Spacer(),

                                     TextButton.icon(
                                       onPressed: stopAudio,
                                       style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                         foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                       ),
                                       icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                                       label: Text(""),

                                     ),

                                   ],
                                 ),
                                 Spacer(),
                                 Text(
                                   "PLAY AUDIO FROM INTERNET",
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                       fontSize: 20,
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                 ),
                                 Row(
                                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                   children: <Widget>[
                                     TextButton.icon(
                                       //onPressed:(){},
                                       onPressed: () async {
                                         await audioo.open(Audio.network(url));
                                       },
                                       style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                         foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                       ),
                                       icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                                       label: Text(""),
                                     ),

                                     Spacer(),
                                     TextButton.icon(
                                       onPressed:stopAudio,
                                       style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                         foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                       ),
                                       icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                                       label: Text(""),
                                     ),

                                   ],
                                 ),
                               ],
                             ),
                             ),

                    ],

                    )

         ],
          ),
         ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to implement the "audio player" widget in my application, but I am not able to. The class is "StatelessWidget"